# Modification of MySQL SELECT variable order results in error

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL v5.6.21 (installed via homebrew) on a Mac OS X Mavericks machine.  I'm using the WordPress wp_options table, but as far as I can tell this is applicable to any table.

I can work around this error, but I found it odd and am curious why MySQL functions this way.  Bug or feature?

Executes properly:
    `SELECT *, CRC32(option_id) FROM wp_options`

Does not execute:
    `SELECT CRC32(option_id), * FROM wp_options`

Given error:
    `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM wp_options' at line 1`

Comment: * will already select all the fields. If you already select a value you can't use *.

Comment: @LelioFaieta - that's not accurate.  You can use * even with specific fields selected: `SELECT *, my_field AS foo FROM my_table` is perfectly valid, or `SELECT table1.*, table2.my_field FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON .... `, or any variety of other situations.

Comment: @cale_b what would be the meaning of choosing two times the same element? Once in the wildcard and the other specifically?

Comment: @LelioFaieta - that's beside the point.  You stated "..you can't use *", and my point is that's not accurate.  And, to your point, you may want to do something like: `SELECT table1.*, table2.my_field AS another_name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON .... `

Comment: @cale_b Ok, you are right. Maybe since I am not english motherthongue I haven't been so precise in order to explain what I meant ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)
>
> - ...
> - Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may
>     produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified
>     tbl_name.* reference
>
>   `SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...`
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
SELECT CRC32(`option_id`), `wp_options`.* FROM `wp_options`;
```

Comment: Nice clarification.  I've learned something (yet again) on SO!